# Why I can´t get the polygons of the PCoA graphics?

Tags: r

When I analyze the beta diversity by the Jaccard index and execute the function to compare the beta diversities of communities added by the group treatments, the generated PCoA graph does not build the polygons as its shown on figure PCoA graph with polygons added from Muñoz-Li & Jover, 2020.

[image]

The graphic that is generated is also uploaded the graphic that is generated by our script.

[image]

I use this script:

```
library(betapart)
library(vegan)
setwd('D:/Trabajo/Docencia/Tutorias/PIE 2022/Malacofauna/Analisis diversity')
BetaAll=read.csv('DivBetaAll.csv', sep=';')
groups= factor(c(rep(1,1), rep(2,1), rep(3,1), rep(4,1)))
dist<-beta.pair(BetaAll, index.family="jaccard")
dist[[3]] # To get all beta diversity
dist[[2]] # To get the pairwise Jaccard index nestedness partition
dist[[1]] # To get the pairwise Jaccard index turnover partition between communities
bd<-betadisper(dist[[3]],groups) # If we want to compare the beta diversities of communities aggregated by the treatments of groups 
plot(bd)
bdboxplot(bd)
anova(bd)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your data, you can try to modify this.
library(betapart)
library(vegan)

```
# Cargar el conjunto de datos mtcars
data(mtcars)

# Convertir la matriz de datos a una matriz binaria de presencia/ausencia
datos.bin <- ifelse(mtcars > 0, 1, 0)

# Calcular la distancia beta utilizando la matriz binaria
dist <- beta.pair(datos.bin, index.family="jaccard")

# Convertir la matriz de distancia a un objeto de distancia
dist <- as.dist(dist[[3]])

# Definir los grupos de tratamiento
groups <- factor(c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 8), rep(3, 8)))

# Calcular la betadispersión y graficar
bd <- betadisper(dist, groups)
plot(bd, main="Betadispersión", sub="Grupos 1, 2, 3")
boxplot(bd)
anova(bd)
```

[image]